# Is there a pubxml setting to delete folder on production prior to publishing using Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, msdeploy, webdeploy, pubxml

I am deploying visual studio project that contains Angular 5 application that is built in dist subfolder. Because dist subfolder is not a part of the project, I am copying it using the publishing profile settings (in .pubxml file):

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
<Message Text="=== CustomCollectFiles ===" Importance="high" />
<ItemGroup>
  <_CustomFiles Include="dist\**\*" />
  <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
    <DestinationRelativePath>dist\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
  </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
</ItemGroup>
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
     CustomCollectFiles;
  $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

<CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  CustomCollectFiles;
  $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works fine the first time but on subsequent deployments the dist folder doesn't get updated. I thought of deleting it first before publishing so it's updated every time but I can't find the xml tag/setting for that.
Is there a setting/tag to delete the folder dist on production prior to publishing?